# Basis on $\Bbb R^3$ for the set of vectors in the plane $2x-y-z=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure I'm understanding this right, please correct me if I'm wrong.

First of all, the plane means the graph of the equation (I'm almost sure I've got that one right). In that case, my reasoning is that since $x=y=z=0$ is a solution, then the origin is an element of the plane. If that's true, then the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^3$ should also be a basis for the set of vectors in the plane. So I guess I could say that $B=\{(x), (y), (z)\}$ is a basis for the plane in question; this seems too easy, and I'm considering the possibility that all my understanding of basis is wrong. Am I wrong?

Comment: Consider some points like (1,0,0), (0,1,0), or (0,0,1). None of these are on your plane yet they are in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Take two other points $P$ and $Q$ in your plane. The possibility that $OP$ and $OQ$ be colinear is very small however you have to verify this two vectors are linearly independant. This give a base of the two-dimensional plane (not a base of three elements: this will be all the space and not your plane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all $(x),(y),(z)$ aren't vectors, they're axis names in parentheses. Second of all, remember that planes are $2$-dimensional, so any basis will have exactly $2$ elements. (By definition the dimension of a space is the size of a basis.)

From this we conclude that any set of $2$ linearly-independent vectors in your plane will span it. We see that $(0,1,-1)$ is in the plane because

> $$2(0)+1-(-1)=0$$

Similarly we have $(1,1,1)$ is in the plane and since neither is a multiple of the other, they are linearly independent, so one basis is

> $$\mathcal{B}=\{(0,1,-1),(1,1,1)\}.$$

Comment: Thanks, this showed me what I needed to know to understand this kind of problem. If I may ask a question, How can one be sure that every element on the plane can be written as a linear combination of those 2 (or any 2) linearly independent vectors? I mean, Couldn't there be like one strange value that you can't write as a combination of those 2 vectors? I'm guessing the answer is that it has been proven to always be that way for linearly independent vectors, but I figured I'd ask. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rise That's the definition of a basis and dimension. Since a plane has dimension $2$, any basis has size $2$. But then any $2$ linearly-independent vectors are a basis, and a basis is a **spanning set**, that is to say by definition it's a set from which you can get any other vector in your set. So basically it's the definition of a basis.

Comment: @Rise You can prove to yourself that there is no such strange value. Take an arbitrary vector $(x,y,z)$ and set it equal to $a(0,1,-1)+b(1,1,1)=(b,b+a,b-a)$. This will give you three equations in the two unknowns $a$ and $b$, which should have a unique solution if the vector is in the plane and no solution otherwise.